# Frame acknowledgement in CAN bus

Tags: can-bus

How does the sender on the CAN bus know that a node has not properly received the data?

I am currently learning the functioning of the CAN bus. Based on what I have seen so far a receiver drives the bus to a dominant state when it successfully obtains a packet and one receiving node is enough to accomplish this. However, in the event where the intended receiver does not successfully obtain the packet while others do, how is the sender made aware of the situation so that it can retransmit the packet?

Any help in providing some clarity on this topic is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "in the event where the intended receiver does not successfully obtain the packet while others do" How does that error even happen? You mean a completely disconnected node?

Comment: @Lundin CAN messages are broadcast, so all nodes on the bus receive and acknowledge all messages. But after that, they may simply ignore the ones they are not interested. They have hardware filters for that, but they acknowledge even the messages they ignore.

Comment: @Tagli I know. So the question is what the OP means, because if a node successfully receives a message and then the software chose to throw that message in the garbage, that's no business/fault of the CAN bus itself. On the CAN data link level, a message can't mysteriously get processed fine by all nodes except one.

Answer (score 0):

The sender can't know this unless you implement a higher layer protocol. The ACK slot in raw CAN frame allows sender to detect if it (not the receiver) has a bus problem. If the sender doesn't sample an ACK, it can conclude that "No one is hearing me in the bus. Maybe I'm physically disconnected or something is completely wrong."

For example in CANopen, it's generally receivers job to complain if an expected PDO packet doesn't arrive on time. Although it's not correct to talk about masters and slaves in CAN bus, a device you assign a master role can be programmed to expect periodic PDO report packets from its slaves, and can rise an error flag if they don't arrive in expected time window.